# Why this variation occurs in the usage of definite article before plural uncountable noun 'police'

Tags: articles, headlinese

In my grammar book it is written that the definite article is used before the armed forces.  For example: *the police, the army*.

The book also explained it by giving examples such as:

> 1. I think you should call **the police**.
> 2. **The police** are investigating fraud allegations against him.

But in the newspaper, I see some lines such as:

> 1. **Police** say the accused illegally exported beef.
> 2. **Police** have arrested three persons.

Could you explain why these variations are seen?

Comment: Newspapers don't use grammatically correct English.

Comment: Your grammar does not cover newspaper style.

Comment: @AndyGould - I don't think it's correct to say "Newspapers don't use grammatically correct English"; *headlinese* doesn't adhere to standard grammar rules, but the OP doesn't say this is a headline.  Body text of newspaper articles is usually fairly standard English.

Comment: @stangdon Depends on the newspaper you read to be fair. I assumed from the example sentences the OP was talking about headlines.

Comment: @ColleenV: the accepted answer to that question seems to lose the plot, but the second answer (Collin Day) comes to the same conclusion as FumbleFingers', but from a different perspective. It's a pity that we can't  merge the two questions.

Comment: @JavaLatte If the question or answers are upvoted, marking as a duplicate just links the questions together, like this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4492/ Closing as a duplicate just forces answers to one of the questions in the future instead of having them spread across both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: *I saw a suspicious-looking man hiding in the bushes in the park, so I called **the** police.*
>   From Google Books, [*I called **the** police then*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20called%20the%20police%20then%22):472 hits; [*I called police then*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%20called%20police%20then%22):1 hit
>    (included "then" to ensure I only matched contexts where the preceding clause was "complete").
>
> 2: *Acting on my tip-off, **the** police arrested him*.
>    [*yesterday **the** police arrested*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22yesterday%20the%20police%20arrested%22):324 hits; [*yesterday police arrested*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22yesterday%20the%20police%20arrested%22#tbm=bks&q=%22yesterday%20police%20arrested%22):85 hits
>    (included "yesterday" for the same reason)

You can see from the above that *police* are normally referenced using the definite article, but this tendency is far less pronounced in the *second* context. This is because in the first example, ***the*** police represents *the entire organisation/service, collectively* (a specific known thing, which merits an article) - but in the second example, you could reasonably say it references ***some*** individual **police** officers.

> 

EDIT: More than likely this question will be closed as a duplicate. But I still think it's worth including here [@anaximander's comment on the "original" page...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59100/police-said-why-not-the-police-said#comment112946_59102)

> *"Police" doesn't change for the plural, like "sheep". So, saying "police said" is like saying "teachers said" - it refers to **a number of** police, rather than the police, which refers to **the organisation**. What makes it confusing is the omitted words - in the first, it's "police officers said", while the second is "the police force said".*

Answer (score 2):

In English, the definite article **the** is used to refer to specific instances of something.  For example, in the phrase "the armed forces of Brazil", we use *the* because we are referring to specific armed forces.  In "call the police", we use *the* because we're referring specifically to the local police that we want to call.

When we want to refer to a plural noun in general, we don't use an article.  (This is sometimes called the *zero article*.)  For example,

> Rabbits got into my garden and ate all my lettuce.

We don't use an article here because we are referring to a general number of nonspecific rabbits.  But we would say

> Mr. Jones, the rabbits that you bought last week got into my garden and ate all my lettuce.

because here we are referring to specific rabbits - the ones that Mr. Jones bought last week.

In the case of your newspaper article, it would not be grammatically wrong to say

> The police are investigating

if we are referring to specific, known police.  But if we want to refer to police in general, we don't use the article.  In English, it's very common to not use the article when we're referring to something as an institution, like *courts* or *police*.

Helpful links:
[When to Use Articles Before Nouns](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-use-articles-before-nouns)
[Using Articles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/) 
[Zero Article in English Grammar](http://www.icaltefl.com/zero-article-in-english-grammar)

Comment: RE: _It would not be wrong to say "The police are investigating" if we are referring to specific, known police_ - It would also not be wrong to say "The police" when you mean "The police department" or "Some police officers." These don't need to be "specific, known" police. For example: _Fairfax Media revealed last week that the police were investigating whether the payment by Tabcorp breached Australia's foreign bribery laws_ (Source: [Syndey Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/business/markets/asx-chief-elmer-funke-kupper-quits-in-face-of-investigation-20160321-gnn1m3.html)).