# Grammar on A and B "is" or "are"

Tags: verb-forms

As a general rule, a sentence that begins with noun A and noun B should be followed by a "plural" form of the verb. For example, May and Tom are good students.

However, which verb should be used in the following example?

Example

> The diagnosis **and** management of disease X require/requires an
>   extensive ...

As in the first example, the original sentence can be broken into

> May is a good student.
>
> Tom is a good student.
>
> May **and** Tom are good students.

Following the logic,

> The diagnosis of disease X requires ....
>      The management of disease X requires ....

Shouldn't `the diagnosis AND management of disease X` be followed by `require`? Or is there any difference between `the diagnosis and management of disease X` and `THE diagnosis and THE management of disease X`, in which the subject in the former is considered singular and that in the latter is plural?

Comment: Marking questions as duplicates is, in fact, specifically intended to help with the problem that questions are often hard to search for. No blame is intended and there's no "slack" to cut; it's just a practical way to keep things together.

Comment: I really dislike some of the "[canned](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/canned "prepared in advance for repeated use")" messages SE has for certain actions because they don't reflect the intent behind the action very well. You may want to read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ - it explains that having several variations of the same question is a good thing. Closing this question as a duplicate is not the same thing as trying to delete it. There are closed as duplicate questions from 3 years ago still on the site.

Comment: Based on my limited experience on other stack exchange forums/groups, I have been under the impression that once a question is marked as a duplicate, they will go into the cyber-dumpster and no longer be searchable. It's all cool but I just never like THAT policy (as for most people who ask questions, it's not because they have too much free time and like to troll. It's because they have a question and couldn't find (know how to find) the answer.

Comment: Duplicate questions don't disappear if they have been upvoted or have upvoted answers. This question was closed as a duplicate three years ago and is still around and searchable: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4492/. Part of the usefulness of duplicate questions is that they give different ways to find the "master" question and they link a bunch of related but maybe slightly different questions together. The 'master' question doesn't necessarily have to be the 'best' - it's just the place where everything is linked together and where all new answers should get directed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OP's specific example, both singular and plural verb forms are fine. It really just depends on whether the speaker thinks of *diagnosis and management* as two distinct things, or two components of a composite "medical response". Speaking for myself, I would tend to the latter interpretation.

That's why we can say, for example, *Fish and chips **is** a British tradition.*

Comment: So you'd probably choose "the diagnosis and management", not "the diagnosis and the management". Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Probably I *would*, but [**the** long and **the** short of it **is**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+long+and+the+short+of+it+is%22) there's no "grammatical rule" saying I can't repeat the article even when I'm treating the combination as syntactically singular.

Comment: So is there a general rule? "Fish and chips is a British tradition" is considered ok but I think, say, "Alice and Bob is in Britain" is considered wrong. Why can't I consider "Alice and Bob" as a "single" group of two people, which "is" in Britain?

Comment: @Mathaholic: No, there's no hard&fast rule beyond what I said in the answer (but you might find [this ELU answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/117351/2637) helpful). It's not easy to think of a context where two *people's names* could reasonably be treated as a single unit for this purpose outside of somewhat contrived contexts like [*Janet and John is a children's book*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Janet-John-Here-Go-Books/dp/1840246138?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0), or *Higgins and O'Sullivan is the snooker final I'm really looking forward to.*